# How to get max value AND respective column name with pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df that looks something like this, but with a lot more columns

```
Item      Raw    Juice   Jelly
Apples     2       5       3
Grapes     1       3       4
Bananas    7       3       5
```

So far I was trying to create two new columns, one with highest value and one with the respective uh... form? Sorry if I'm not using the corret words. Anyway, it would end up looking something like this:

```
Item      Raw    Juice   Jelly   HighestValue   Form
Apples     2       5       3           5        Juice
Grapes     1       3       4           4        Jelly
Bananas    7       3       5           7        Raw
```

The goal is to figure out in which way each fruit is more expensive, so I can later easily get the most expensive fruit, it's price and it's form.

```
print(f'The most expensive fruit is {fruit}, worth ${price} as {form}.')
> 'The most expensive fruit is bananas, worth $7 as raw.'
```

I did get the max value with argmax, but I can't figure out how to also get the respective column name. Is there a better way to do this? It doesn't even have to be new columns in the df, but I can't think of another way to do this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'Item': {0: 'Apples', 1: 'Grapes', 2: 'Bananas'},
        'Raw': {0: 2, 1: 1, 2: 7},
        'Juice': {0: 5, 1: 3, 2: 3},
        'Jelly': {0: 3, 1: 4, 2: 5}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['Higest Value'] = df.apply(lambda x: max([x['Raw'], x['Juice'], x['Jelly']]), axis=1)
df['Form'] = df.apply(lambda x: ['Raw', 'Juice', 'Jelly'][np.argmax([x['Raw'], x['Juice'], x['Jelly']])], axis = 1)

print(df)
#output:
      Item  Raw  Juice  Jelly  Higest Value   Form
0   Apples    2      5      3             5  Juice
1   Grapes    1      3      4             4  Jelly
2  Bananas    7      3      5             7    Raw
```

For a solution that can be generalized to more columns, use slicing:

```
df['Higest Value'] = df.apply(lambda x: max(x[1:4]), axis=1)
df['Form'] = df.apply(lambda x: df.columns[1:4][np.argmax(x[1:4])], axis = 1)
```

Comment: Oh yeah, I did forget to edit the bananas input lol thanks for the heads up. Also, it's working perfectly! Is there a way I could make it check more columns, maybe by index or something, or I can only do this expliciting every column name?

Answer (score 0):

You can use lambda function for that:

```
data = {
'Item' : ['Apples','Grapes','Bananas'],
'Raw' : [20,1,7],
'Juice':[5,30,3],
'Jelly' : [5,4,70]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['HighestValue'] = df.apply(lambda row: max(row[1:].tolist()) , axis = 1 )
df['Form'] = df.apply(lambda row: 
df.columns[row.tolist().index(max(row[1:-1].tolist()))] , axis = 1 )
df

#Output:

    Item    Raw Juice   Jelly   HighestValue    Form
0   Apples  20  5       5       20              Raw
1   Grapes  1   30      4       30              Juice
2   Bananas 7   3       70      70              Jelly
```

Note: To avoid type error you can select only numerical values:

```
df_num = df._get_numeric_data() # will bring all numeric columns
df_str = df.select_dtypes(include='object') #will bring all string columns

df_num['HighestValue'] = df_num.apply(lambda row: max(row.tolist()) , axis = 1 )
df_num['Form'] = df_num.apply(lambda row: 
df_num.columns[row.tolist().index(max(row.tolist()))] , axis = 1 )
```

Then you can combine your df_num and df_str dataframes:

```
df_combined = pd.concat([df_str , df_num], axis=1)
```

Comment: The values in the Jelly column are the same as those in the HighestValue column.

Comment: It picks highest value in the row. It just a coincidence. You can try with different values.

Comment: The input values in the Jelly column are 3,4, and 5.

Comment: I changed the inputs

Comment: Your code did work, but it didn't work specifically with my df because I have some columns with strings and it returns a TypeError

Comment: I remove string columns by using indices like row[1:-1] : exclude first and last columns which are strings. You can arrange your dataset like that.

Comment: I added an alternative solution to avoid type error. Please check out.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
df.assign(Largestvalue = df.iloc[:,1:].max(axis=1),Form = df.iloc[:,1:].idxmax(axis=1))
```